# How to post calendar events to Google Calendar from .NET web application

Tags: c#, .net, calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to post calendar events from my .NET web application to (authenticated) users' Google Calendar API.

How can my users grant my web app the necessary permissions for their calendar ahead of time, so they don't have to repeatedly authorize my app each time a calendar entry is created?

I see from this site:
https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#OAuth2Authorizing

> 4. Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
> 5. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.

This won't work for me. My users are not on a single G Suite domain, so I cannot perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.

Is it possible for users to give me some secret token to authorize my app to insert calendar entries in their Google Calendar?

I'm also trying to do this for Outlook Calendar (which some users use), but maybe that's something for another post.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why won't this work? This is the non G Suite domain approach. The only thing that changes in the G Suite option, is that you can delegate the authority there. There js no other way to go. This is how oauth works.

Comment: Ask for offline access and save the refresh token you get back then use the refresh token to request access of the users again later when they are not online to grant you access.   Your only option is to use Oauth2 and have them authorize your application once.